# Is it possible to create a searchable multi select box in observablehq?

Tags: observablehq

I would like to create a searchable multi select box in `observablehq` that would not consume too much space when, for example, 50+ values are selected (in my usecase, all values are selected by default). I am aware that some custom searchable multi select options exist for `observablehq` such as [this one](https://observablehq.com/@john-guerra/multi-auto-select) and [this table based multiselect](https://observablehq.com/@abenrob/table-based-multi-select), but the first one takes up too much space when a lot of values are selected. The table based one does not work for me because the search box overrides what has been (un)selected in the table. An example of what I am after would be on [this page](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/multi-select/grouping-with-checkbox/). In addition to what I have described above (searchable multi select that neatly handles a lot of selections), they also have the **(un)select all** options, and **option groups**, which are really cool features that I do not need right now, but feel like they can be handy. I tried to use a regular `JavaScript` solution, but it does not seem to be working in `observablehq`, possibly because I try to manipulate the DOM. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f03bjaw5/) is a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now seems to be possible thanks to the wonderful John's [Search Checkbox](https://observablehq.com/@john-guerra/search-checkbox).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question! Here's an approach using Observable Inputs components to keep track of the selected items.

Let me know if this works for you!

https://observablehq.com/d/7f90eca860f55f3d

Comment: it seems like the notebook you linked is not published. The page says "You either don’t have permission to view this notebook, or it doesn’t exist.".

Comment: Sorry about that! You should be able to view it now.

Comment: I am afraid this is not what I need. The problem with the search is that it overrides values (un)/selected with the multiselect. I want to search only manage what is **displayed** by the multiselect, not making the selection.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is explicit about why the table based solution is not possible.